# Gnuplot polar plot with top theta clockwise keeps the inner radial grid origin at 0 angle

Tags: plot, gnuplot, polar-coordinates, radar-chart

I have a simple time/value dataset like this:

```
1   20
2   21
# ...
15  36
```

Where the first column is a time value, and other columns store some measurements. I wanted to plot these values in a "clock plot", that is a polar plot (or a radar chart) where angles correspond to time instants, and the radius keeps the value of the measurement.

Since I would like to reproduce a clock, I want my first measurement to start in a vertical position, and I can do `set theta top clockwise`. Having 15 seconds in my dataset, I can split the 360 degrees in angles of 24 degrees (one for each second) `set grid polar 24`.

However, the grid values start from the 0 degree angle (and not, as expected, from the top angle of 90 degrees). This bothers me because my measurements have an offset with respect to the grid. (Check the picture attached).

How can I solve this problem? Can I rotate the grid to start counting at 90 degrees? Thank you a lot in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you could draw your grid lines manually. Not very nice but you visually get the desired result.

**Code:**

```
### polar grids aligned to north
reset session
set size square
set angle degrees

set polar
set theta clockwise top
unset border
set border polar
unset xtics
unset ytics
set ttics 24 format ""
set rtics 10
set grid rtics
unset key

set rrange[0:40]

# manually draw grid lines
do for [i=0:360:24] {
    set arrow i+1 from 0,0 to polar i,40 lw 0.5 dt 3 lc rgb "black" nohead
}

set samples 16
plot t/9 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems that I really have to manually draw the grid lines, although I hoped for a sort of builtin solution.

Comment: maybe there is a built-in solution or trick, but which I don't know of and I haven't found.